# How to design relationship betwen these django models?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, model

I have to make this Django Rest Framework API which can book Advisors from the available lists of advisors through the specific endpoint `user/<user-id>/advisor/<advisor-id>` (and i am logged in as user)

Models i have(models.py) :

```
#User
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Custom user model that supports email instead of username"""
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

#Advisor
class Advisor(models.Model):
    """Advisor object to be booked"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=advisor_image_file_path)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 
#Booking
class Booking(models.Model):
    """Booking the Advisor"""
    advisor = models.ForeignKey(
        Advisor,
        default = '' ,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE 
    )
  
    date_time_field = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        default = 1
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.date_time_field)
```

I don't know if this logic is correct or not but i am getting error `core.booking has no column advisor_id` while trying to get Bookingtime at the required endpoint.

If this is not the correct logic, please suggest the correct one.

Edit :
Error i am getting :

```
OperationalError at /user/12/advisor/5/

table core_booking has no column named advisor_id
```

log :

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 13, 2021 - 11:13:34
Django version 2.1.15, using settings 'App.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Not Found: /user/
[13/May/2021 11:13:44] "GET /user/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3077
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[13/May/2021 11:13:48] "GET /user/login HTTP/1.1" 301 0
Method Not Allowed: /user/login/
[13/May/2021 11:13:48] "GET /user/login/ HTTP/1.1" 405 7460
[13/May/2021 11:13:56] "POST /user/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7891
Not Found: /user/12/
[13/May/2021 11:14:24] "GET /user/12/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3086
[13/May/2021 11:14:33] "GET /user/12/advisor/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7761
[13/May/2021 11:14:34] "GET /static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 121457
----------------------------------------
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 49194)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
[13/May/2021 11:14:36] "GET /user/12/advisor/5 HTTP/1.1" 301 0
Method Not Allowed: /user/12/advisor/5/
[13/May/2021 11:14:36] "GET /user/12/advisor/5/ HTTP/1.1" 405 7411
Internal Server Error: /user/12/advisor/5/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 298, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table core_booking has no column named advisor_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 192, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 21, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 26, in perform_create
    serializer.save()
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 214, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 943, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 413, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 717, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 748, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 831, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 868, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk,
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1136, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1322, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rahulnegi/projects/BookAdvisor.01/point0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 298, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table core_booking has no column named advisor_id
[13/May/2021 11:16:15] "POST /user/12/advisor/5/ HTTP/1.1" 500 205173
```

Comment: Please share the *full* traceback.

Comment: Run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem please check the edited post

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat nothing changed

Comment: @RahulNegi try `python manage.py makemigrations core` (`core` is your app name I assume), does that generate any migrations? (if it does run `python manage.py migrate`), else for some reason it appears that the relevant migration is marked as applied in the database while it is in fact not.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, it is  not running though i have used python manage.py migrate --fake command sometimes when the migrations was causing error, is it what effecting my model now? if yes how to correct this now? (should i delete the Booking model and start once again?) + is this the correct logic to get the desired result?   Thanks

Comment: @RahulNegi If you ran `python manage.py migrate --fake` then yes that should be the problem as you have marked the migration as applied (even though it is not)... Generally one should not use these commands without knowing what they are doing. You now need to figure out exactly which migrations are applied and fake _back_ to the proper one, etc.